# PDF Bookmarks in Chrome and IE

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I am wondering if anyone can help me with an issue I am having with Chrome and IE.
I have a PDF document which has bookmarks on it. I have uploaded the PDF and I have linked a piece of text to this document - Something like "click here to read this article". The 'here' is hyperlinked to the PDF bookmark using #namedest='destination name'
This works perfectly in Firefox. I click on 'here' and the PDF document opens up and brings me to the correct bookmark. However in IE and Chrome when I click 'here' the PDF opens but only brings me to the top of the page with the bookmark.
Is there anyway to get the PDF to open at the bookmark (half way down the page) rather then the top in IE and Chrome?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually create definitions in the PDF? Sounds like FFox is using some hackery because you cannot directly link to bookmarks, only definitions or page #'s. If you have a PDF editor/full/whatever, then you can create some definitions - if not then if I were you I'd just resort to using #page=